# CMake fails while trying to generate a Visual Studio 2012 ARM configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, cmake, arm

I'm trying to build CLucene library *v 2.3.3.2) for WinRT using the CMake tool, v 2.8.11.2.
In the specify Generator for this project, I select Visual Studio 12 ARM. I have VS 2012 Ultimate installed.
When I select the "Use default native compilers", and then press Generate, I get the following errors:

CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Visual Studio 12 ARM".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:c:/CLucene-ARM/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:c:/CLucene-ARM/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake

I thought it's not able to find the C++ compiler, so even if I manually set the C and C++ compilers to this value in the other "Specify native compilers" to C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/bin/x86_arm/cl.exe, I get the same error above.

I've browsed a lot of posts, but haven't seen anyone face this issue with VS2012 Ultimate. I did come across that some people had a similar issue for VS 2012 Express, but it was mentioned that it'd be fixed in CMake v2.8.11, but it doesn't appear to be the case.

I'd appreciate if someone can point out if I'm missing something here, or I need to point to the right compilers?

Thanks in advance,
Asheesh

Answer (score 35):

Visual C++ 2012 is called Visual Studio 11 in cmake.
It is very confusing.

Try to select the Visual Studio 11 ARM target.

Comment: Microsoft logic. 12==11 and 7==6.1 (windows 7 == NT 6.1)

Comment: Microsoft calls it Visual Studio 11.0 also: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/'

Comment: @Rickard Visual Studio 2012 is Visual Studio 11 and not 12==11. It's just counting. VS2010 is 10, VS2008 is 9, ...

Answer (score 12):

2012 is the version of IDE, not the year of relase:

```
VS2010  =  v10
VS2012  =  v11
```

The latest (preview only) version is

```
VS2013  = v12.
```